# How do I specify that I want Vim to treat .ru files like .rb files

Tags: ruby, vim, rack

Whenever I use Vim with Ruby files, I get nice coloring and automatic indention on blocks. However, when I am editing a Rack file, I don't get these things. How can I extend my Vim/Ruby configuration with my Rack files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put this in your `vimrc` to tell vim to associate *.ru files with ruby syntax highlighting.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ru setfiletype ruby
```

Comment: It looks like my vimrc was only mapping config.ru to Ruby. FWIW, my vimrc uses "set ft=ruby" as shorthand for setfiletype ruby. Thank-you dmarkow!

Answer (score 6):

Ensure the following lines are in your `vimrc` file:

```
syntax on
filetype on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ru set filetype=ruby
```

The first two are probably *already* set if other files are syntax-colored, but I've put them there anyway.

The final one sets automatic actions on creating a new file and opening an existing file, to set the file type based on the extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the `vim-ruby` [plugin](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) by [tpope](https://github.com/tpope), which will do this and much more!

Comment: Thank-you for the recommendation!